# xml parsing using xpath and xquery

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file

```
<events date="30/08/2010">
<event>
<title>here</title>
<description>
This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event This is first Event
</description>
</event>
</events>
<events date="31/08/2010">
<event>
<title>Second Event </title>
<description>
Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event Second Event
</description>
</event>
</events>
```

from this xml how i can select the event with title  Second Event using xquery.I used

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//xml/events/event[@title="'.$title.'"]');
```

but it is not working, can anybody help me

Comment: Take a look to http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp, this should help you understand XPath syntax better.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to name an element "xml". Quoting from section 2.3 of XML 1.0: 

"Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//xml/events/event[title="'.$title.'"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a node called "xml" so your query should not start "xml". Title is not an attribute, so remove the "@". This (untested) ought to work:

```
//events/event[title="'.$title.'"]'
```

and return a node list.

Comment: My xml is start with xml thats y i used .I tried this one then also it is not working

Comment: @THOmas the above works fine for me with the XML you show in your question. Just make sure you use `Second Event ` with the trailing space to find the node or switch to `/events/event[normalize-space(title)="Second Event"]` or - better - `/events/event[contains(title, "Second Event")]`